# issue with array reference in php

Tags: php, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

I am trying to run following code:

```
$a = array('aa');

function my_func (& $m) {
    return $m;
}

$c = & my_func($a);
$c[] = 'bb';
var_dump($a);
echo '--------';
var_dump($c);
```

My expectation were that $a and $c would have same reference. But the result is different.

Result i got was:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "aa" } --------array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "aa" [1]=> string(2) "bb" }
```

What is wrong in above piece of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is function [returning by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) (this in conjunction with [passing by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) in your example).

Here is an example:

```
function &my_func(&$m) {
    return $m;
}

$a = array('aa');
$c = &my_func($a);
$c[] = 'bb';

var_dump($a);
echo "---\n";
var_dump($c);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "aa"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "bb"
}
---
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "aa"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "bb"
}
```

Comment: I dint know about returning by reference in php. Thanks. Coming from a non-php background, this is really different for me. And i fear, i dont introduce some unintentional bugs. :(